# How to limit fields returned in django queryset per field

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have rows of products, that tend to share some information, such as the same images (an image may show multiple products), descriptions, manufacturer, etc.

I would like to choose some fields to only show the information once. I can't use distinct for this (I don't think) as the information is not always identicle, such as with the description, but may be only subtly different enough that I don't want to repeat it.

At the moment, I am using a for loop to display fields from each result, which ends up with something like this:[image: this:]

This is the code I am using in my view:

```
def collection_detail(request, name=None):
    template = loader.get_template('/webapps/mywebapp/furniture/main_page/templates/main_page/detail.html')
    products = product.objects.filter(id=name)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    context={'products': products,
    'cart_product_form': cart_product_form}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

What would be the appropriate way to do this in a view, ignoring subsequent rows for some fields?

edit: Example queryset results

```
collection_name|manufacturer|product_type|description|image_url
----------------------------------------------------------------
Testing        |FakeCo      |Bed         |pretty nice|/img/1.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Desk        |pretty bad |/img/2.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Nightstand  |pretty ok  |/img/1.jpg
Testing        |FakeCo      |Draws       |pretty nice|/img/3.jpg
```

In the example of the above data, I want to show the collection name and manufacturer just once, so the first result would do, each product type, the first description regardless of what it says, and each image that is distinct and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
products = product.objects.filter(id=name)
collection_name = []
manufacturer = []
product_type = []
description = []
image_url = []
for product in products:
    collection_name.append(product.collection_name)
    manufacturer.append(product.manufacturer)
    product_type.append(product.product_type)
    description.append(product.description)
    image_url.append(product.image_url)
collection_name = set(collection_name)
manufacturer = set(manufacturer)
product_type = set(product_type)
description = set(description)
image_url = set(image_url)
```

It is little long but it will solve your problem. "set" will make all common names once in the list.

Comment: Interesting I am testing this now thank you...this is educational as well, I had no idea I could do something like this. Question, what about making image_url distinct, I would add in with what is in the for loop correct?

Comment: Image has some properties we can not do the same with the images, just use the distinct images for your project.

Comment: I'm unsure how to use .distinct() here, would it be `image_url = product.image_url.distinct()` ?

Comment: You can do the same for the images.

Comment: Hmm, nothing seems to have changed when using this view. Do I have to do anything different in template?

Comment: all lists(collection_name, manufacturer, ..) have distinct data now you can use it anywhere to display names in your code and to debug use pdb.

Comment: I didn't change my template at all (as I assumed I didn't have to), but many fields are repeating.despite being the same. Is there an easy way to just use the 'first' description field, as the descriptions are not distinct, but similar enough that I don't want to repeat them

Comment: you have to change your template as well, where you want to display collection name just use "collection_name" this and same for rest.

Comment: I was about to ask a new question regarding this, but I can't get anything to display in the template. I switched from instance.collection_name to just collection_name and this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

By this

```
products = product.objects.filter(id=name)
```

it will return a queryset, that means it consists of several products information.
If you want to get only single objects information change the query like below:

```
products = product.objects.filter(id=name).first()
or,
products = product.objects.filter(id=name)[:1]
```

**Update**
If you want to display some fields one value then use this:

```
{{ value|first }}
```

Comment: Well, I don't think that helps in my case though. I want to get all records that match the parameter. The problem is in the template I only want to display some fields once and other fields for as many as they are. For example I want to show the manufacturer once but list each type of product.

Comment: When I use `{{ instance.description|first }}` in my template, only the first letter of each result is returned, but still numerous results are returned.

Comment: can you add a sample products QuerySet output?

Comment: I added example data and example of what I am trying to do.